# compare between input value with 0 trail

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found that when jQuery get a value with 0 (for example 100)trail, it will omit it. So if I compare 5>100, the result is true. So how do I solve this?
here is the HTML code:

```
<form id="target">
    <input type="text" id="max"  value="100"/>
    <input type="text" id="number" />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

And here is jquery:

```
$('#target').submit( function() {
  var a = $("#number").val();
  var b = $("#max").val();
  if( a > b){
     alert("exceed limit"); 
  }

return false;
});
```

Here you can see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yqMGG/91/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compare the numeric values, not the string values.  The output of the `.val()` function is a DOMString value according to [DOM Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-6043025) which says:

> ```
> interface HTMLInputElement : HTMLElement {
>   ...
>   attribute DOMString       value;
>   ...
> }
> ```

so your (5 > 100) test is really `"5" > "100"` which is true since strings are compared lexicographically.

The solution is to change

```
if( a > b){
```

to

```
if(+a > +b){
```

The `+` prefix operator coerces its argument to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseFloat()`, otherwise the values are considered as strings.

```
$('#target').submit( function() {
  var a = parseFloat($("#number").val());
  var b = parseFloat($("#max").val());
  if( a > b){
     alert("exceed limit"); 
  }

    return false;
});
```

See **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arvind07/yqMGG/93/)**

Comment: thanks, your answer is correct, but I accept Mike's answer as the answer since adding + sign is faster and less code. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply it by 1 to convert it from string to number, or use parseInt

```
var a = $("#number").val() * 1;
```

OR

```
var a = parseInt($("#number").val(), 10);
```

the second parameter of parseInt function is the radix.